# Strong AI vs Singularity - which should happen first?

Tags: agi, singularity, superintelligence

What is supposed to happen first: Strong AI or Technological Singularity?

Meaning which option is more likely, that the Strong AI that will bring as to the state of technological singularity or achieving technological singularity will allow us to construct strong AI?

Comment: Charles Stross, in *Accelerando* posits that, even in a post superintelligence future, recognizing the advent or nature of the singularity may be fuzzier than people assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of "technological singularity" answers the question:

> The technological singularity (also, simply, the singularity) is
>   the hypothesis that the invention of artificial superintelligence will
>   abruptly trigger runaway technological growth, resulting in
>   unfathomable changes to human civilization.

([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity))

note the order of facts is "invention of artificial superintelligence" (AGI) followed by the "unfathomable changes".

Comment: Even though I agree, yet there are some scenarios with non-AI singularity.

Comment: @Alex: Of course alternative definitions can be done and answers will differ. My answer wants more to present the need of define the concepts before to discuss about them that advocate for an opinion about "singularities". Talk without concept definition is done on TV shows.

Comment: Solid answer.  I'm not entirely convinced "singularity" is the right word for the definitions given, which is not to impugn Von Neumann, Goode or anyone else.  Just that the after reading the Causal Angel by mathematical phycist Rajaniemi, who uses game theory to relate intelligence acceleration to the topology of blackholes, I feel like the term "singularity" should be more specific than mere "runaway superintelligence."  i.e. why this term in particular?